# Apache Spark Window function, filter by size

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

Am trying to use a Window function to calculate the average within a window but excluding 0's before the calculation.

```
val byClass = Window.partitionBy('class)    
val avgAge = avg('age).over(byClass)
```

I try filtering the size like this but no luck.

```
val avgAge = avg('age).ge(lit(0)).over(byClusterHash)
```

Finally,

```
val results = reports.select('*, avgAge as 'avg).show(2000)
```

Any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: Can you show example data and expected output?

Comment: @mtoto adds the calculated average to the result, so instead of calculating the average of age as (5 + 4 + 0) / `3`, it's calculated as (5 + 4) / `2`

Comment: that's great but your code is still not reproducible.

Comment: @mtoto: there is nothing to reproduce, it's just a basic Window function in spark, just need to know how to apply filter within a groups to exclude some rows.

Comment: if there's nothing to reproduce, there's nothing to answer either.